# Copy Data If content is there

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question related VBA Macro, I want to copy data from table if there is data, like if there no data in row or column it should not be copied
Can you please help me ?

I tried with simple macro and obviously it won't work

```
Sub Copy()
  Range("C2:C6").Select
  Selection.copy
  Range("C8:c19").Select
  Selection.copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy using `SpecialCells` and get cells that have constants in them. If you need formulas as well, you can modify the code.

Here's an example below:

```
Private Sub copyAllButEmpty()
    Dim source As Range
    Set source = Range("C2:C6")
    source.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy

    Dim destination As Range
    Set destination = Range("G2:G6")
    destination.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End Sub
```

Comment: @muiz  If it helps, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Miles, yes somehow this helped it, counting as Yes helps

Thanks a lot

Comment: haha thanks, but I meant to click the checkmark and vote up the answer. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of empty cells in that range, and if it's >0, then copy.

```
Sub copy_filled()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C2:C6")
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) <> 0 Then
    rng.Copy
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Bruce,

still its copying all the content, I have below table see


Domain:- 
KI:- 
Locator Page:- 
Expected Branch Count:- 
Expected Branch Count (Source):- 
Nevigation  (steps)  
1:- 
2:- 
3:- 
4:- 
5:- 
6:- 
7:- 
8:- 
9:- 
10:- 
Example Note:- 
Comment, if any:- 

I want copy data where user is mentioning anything beside above columns

Comment: @muiz can you edit your origin post to include that sample data and expected output? It's hard to understand as a comment

Comment: @muiz are you wanting to ignore blank cells rather than copy the entire `Range`?